Avoid resource leaks in WinForms controls having event handlers for the static SystemEvents.UserPreferenceChanged event
I have a WinForms control inherited from the System.Windows.Forms.Control class. This control subscribes to the SystemEvents.UserPreferenceChanged event in the control's instance constructor. Un-subscription is done in the overridden Dispose() method:
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (disposing)
    {
        SystemEvents.UserPreferenceChanged -= new UserPreferenceChangedEventHandler(SystemEvents_UserPreferenceChanged);
        
        // other resource cleaning operations
    }
    
    base.Dispose(disposing);
}

One of the customers of this component told me that they have scenarios in which this Dispose() method is not called automatically by the standard form infrastructure in WinForms and the instance of the control remains in memory 'forever' because there is a reference to it from the static event SystemEvents.UserPreferenceChanged and the .NET Garbage Collector cannot remove the control instance from memory because of that.
Is there a solution to this problem that will work solely for WinForms platform (using a weak event pattern, replacing SystemEvents.UserPreferenceChanged with the processing of the Windows WM_SETTINGCHANGE message instead, etc.)?

UPDATE: Explanation why the Dispose() method of the control is not called explicitly or implicitly. My customer has a custom form infrastructure in which they define forms in XML files and create the UI on the fly based on such a file. The defined control hierarchy is loaded into a special user control and this control is added to the form. When they do unit testing, forms are even not created - only this special user control is created and tested. As a rule, they do not call the Dispose() method in all this. They have thousands of forms and unit tests so fixing them by inserting the call to the Dispose() method is not a feasible solution for them for several reasons.

Why don't you remove if (disposing) { } from there, the finalizer should call Dispose(false). Possibly, specify why the Control is not disposed, and what Dispose() method is not called automatically by the standard form infrastructure means

Without explicit disposing, a WinForms control is implicitly disposed when its parent control is disposed. Please note that this does not happen if the control is not parented. Please also note that Form.Close() does not dispose the form if it was shown modally (by. ShowDialog). Btw, if your customers are right and the control is not always disposed, then weak events would not solve anything because other references would remain live to the control. Beyond these general things not too much can be said without a reproducible example.

@Jimi, I updated the question and described the form infrastructure of my customer in which the problem occurs. An I didn't understand your idea with the finalizer: it should not be called because the control is not eligible for garbage collection because there is a reference to it because of the event handler for the static event.

@GyörgyKőszeg, is there a good example in the Internet showing how to use a weak event pattern for a .NET Framework WinForms application? I also saw that standard .NET controls like DataGridView attach/detach their event handlers for the SysteEvets.UserPreferenceChanged event in the overridden OnHandleCreated/OnHandleDestroyed methods. Can it help to solve the problems with the resource leak I described?

@TecMan: To be frank, I don't like the weak event pattern at all. I even consider it as an anti-pattern because in most cases it is supposed to conceal a leaking issue instead of fixing it. It's often used in WPF environment where almost nothing is disposable (though even an empty Window or a BitmapSource contains unmanaged resources). And the pattern relies on WeakReference, which is also not disposable so you just put even more burden to the GC, relying on the non-deterministic timing of finalizers. And again, undisposed controls may stuck in the memory via other references as well.

I do agree with @GyörgyKőszeg here. The WPF's WeakEventManager<TEventSource,TEventArgs> also doesn't translate well in WinForms, since it relies on its Dispatcher and DispatcherObject, similar to the WinForms', but not the same, which implies that, e.g., the sender object needs special care. So special that introduces liabilities along the way. Weak Events should be supported by the language itself and the run-time. But, IMO, you don't need any of that. As you mentioned, WM_SETTINGCHANGE is the real deal here

@Jimi, unfortunately WM_SETTINGCHANGE is not sent to form controls - only to top-level windows. This requires the creation of a special hidden top-level window that will intercept this message and send it to the control. I asked about harnessing OnHandleCreated/OnHandleDestroyed for our purpose - WinForms controls like DataGridView do that. Can they help?

Since these Controls are not disposed (as it looks like), how do you know when the handle is going to be destroyed? In any case, you're in the same situation as before: your Control(s) should unsubscribe when the finalizer kicks in (as mentioned before, it should call Dispose(false), hence my first comment) -- You could also add a manager class (as a singleton, probably) that implements IMessageFilter (assuming there's a message loop in that exceedingly weird scenario). This class should be GC-eligible, so you need to also keep it alive. It should clean up when the appdomain is unloaded
